# Android kotlin coroutines, viewModelScope behavior

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I am having this interesting problem. I need to do some work immediately after insertion, but viewModelScope randomly, or at least it looks like randomly, skips functions except for the first one.

Example:

```
fun insertItem(item: SingleItem) = viewModelScope.launch {
        itemsRepository.insertItem(item)
        increaseAmount(item.catId)
    }
```

So in this example everything runs ok only after fresh app install, but then on the next app launches second function "increaseAmount" will be randomly skipped and i don`t know why.
And it doesn't matter what goes after first function. I tried simple "Log" and it gets skipped as well. Is it normal for viewModelScope?

**EDIT**
Checked for exceptions. Second function throws an exception that the job was cancelled:

```
kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled; job=SupervisorJobImpl{Cancelling}@2d87ff
```

Also, in my Fragment it is called like this:

```
viewModel.insertItem(newItem)
root.findNavController().popBackStack()
```

So after calling this function i go back to previous Fragment. Is it possible that viewModel gets destroyed before it finishes executing all work?

Comment: `itemRepository.insertItem` may throw exception. Have you checked it?

Comment: I am facing same issue, in my case after install on first run Skip viewmodelscope.launch code block. If you solved this, than can you explain how you did it?

Answer (score 2):

*Is it normal for viewModelScope?*

No, it is not. In coroutines functions call must be sequential. Functions `itemsRepository.insertItem(item)` and `increaseAmount(item.catId)` **must** be called one after another. I see a couple of reasons why second function is not called:

1. Function `itemsRepository.insertItem(item)` throws some exception.
2. Current coroutine scope is cancelled before second function call.

**Edit**:

`ViewModel` objects are scoped to the `Lifecycle` passed to the `ViewModelProvider` when getting the `ViewModel`. The `ViewModel` remains in memory until the `Lifecycle` it's scoped to goes away permanently: in the case of an activity, when it finishes, while in the case of a fragment, when it's detached.

After you call `root.findNavController().popBackStack()` your fragment will be detached, the `ViewModel` cleared and coroutine job cancelled.
You can initialize the `ViewModel` in the fragment in the following way:

```
private val viewModel: YourViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

Initializing `viewModel` in this way it will be scoped to the `Lifecycle` of an `Activity`.

To use `activityViewModels()` add next line to the dependencies of app's **build.gradle** file:

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"
```

Comment: ok, so i checked for exceptions. The first function doesn't throw any but the second, throws that a job was indeed cancelled. How to check why was it cancelled?

Comment: in Android Studio you can check exceptions in logcat

Comment: the only exception i can see is the one i mentioned above and only after i display it with try/catch